# Angular error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

Tags: angular, typeerror

My app was working fine but after I installed a package and now I get this Error message:

[image]

I tried uninstalling the package, checked if any versions changed somewhere in my app. I don't know where to start with this error code, looked up several questions but none worked on my problem. I'm using Angular 7. Any ideas what can cause it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of searching I figured out that in my `tsconfig.json` 2 lines of code changed. `module` and `target` was `es2016` and `es6`. I changed them back to `es2015` and `es5` and now it works again.